# Javascript recorder works first time, but error "Recording not supported in this browser" after page redirect

Tags: xmlhttprequest, window.location, web-mediarecorder

*My first posting on stackoverflow, so apologies in advance for any lapses in protocol.*

I'm creating a Django web application that has a page to allow the user to record an audio clip using the microphone, then save this clip to the server.  So, user flow is:

- From page with list of past recordings, click "New".
- You're taken to a page with some recorder controls where you hit "Record".
- Say some stuff.
- Click the "Stop" button, which stops recording and makes a "Save" button available.
- Hit the "Save" button; get a popup telling you Save was successful, and then you get taken back to the "index" page with the list of recordings (with your latest recording at the top).

I'm using [Chris Rudmin's opus-recorder](https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder) to handle the recording, and wrote some custom javascript to send the audio as a blob back to the server as an XMLHttpRequest.
There's a Django view on the server that handles the POST, and sends back JSON with success/failure info.
Back on the client side, the user is shown an alert with status, and then the page redirects (using window.location.href and a url sent in the JSON from the server) to the index page.

**Here's the problem:**
Everything works fine the first time I load the page, including saving the recording and redirecting to the index page.  However, from the "index" page if I now click "New", when I go back to the recording page it fails to work.  The console shows me the message

```
Recording is not supported in this browser
```

Now, if I comment out the window.location.href that's doing the redirect, and manually enter the URL for the index page and then click on "New" to come back, everything works fine.
So something about that redirect is messing things up, but I can't figure out what.

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried replacing window.location.href with

```
window.location.replace
```

and

```
window.location.assign
```

but neither of those solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by replacing

```
window.location.href
```

with

```
document.getElementById('home-link').click();
```

It just so happens that there's a link on the page that points to the page I wanted to programatically navigate to, and "clicking" it seems to solve my original problem (i.e. subsequently navigating back to the recording page no longer raises the "Recording not supported..." error).

Comment: While this solved my original problem, it seems somewhat "hacky" and I still don't understand why window.location.href = <newurl> doesn't work, so if anybody can shed some light and/or suggest a better approach I'd be much obliged.